# How to give permission to certain users to see a view based on Parse user type property?

Tags: parse-platform

assume that i have two types of users: **students** and **instructors**. How can I be able to give permission only to **instructors** to go to some different views than **students**, for example

```
ObjectID    UserName   Password    Type
-------     --------   --------   ------
8uJ03j7     user#1      ***        student
2835ruJ     user#2      ***        instructor
2835JhL     user#3      ***        student
```

**Let's say** we have an app for school, students can log in and see just their grades, whereas instructor can enter data and modified.
**i was asking this question because as far as i know you cannot have two Uses Log in class in Parse.com** that is why i wanted to make distinguish between two different types of users. 
*thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your question differently than MannyFle and ismailgulek. My interpretation: Based on what type of user is logging in, you want the app to *automatically* direct them to different views for instructors and students. No buttons to hide etc.

To achieve this, you can do the following in your AppDelegate:

```
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user {
NSString *userType = user[@"type"];
if ([userType isEqualToString:@"instructor"]) {
    self.window.rootViewController = instructorViewController;
} else {
    self.window.rootViewController = studentViewController;            
}

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I'm sure you've already implemented didLogInUser in your appdelegate. Do the check for usertype there. There is no need to use a singleton, as `[PFUser currentUser]` will be available to you anywhere in your app.

You will of course need to initialize the right instructor/studentviewcontrollers inside the if statement, before setting it as `rootViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to prevent any user from logging in. I think it is a very bad way of controlling anything. You can extend `PFUser` class and add an extra field like `type` and do any control after the user login.

Comment: ok, thanks, i have already **"type"** field, but all i want is, when a student logged in, it should let's say go to firstView, and when an instructor logged in goes to secondView. **Do you know how to manage it** i mean where should i put that condition. thanks

Comment: Ok i get it now. I think you should store the user type in a singleton-like object in your application. So maybe there are 3 types of user type: `not logged in`, `logged in student` and `logged in instructor`. So when you come to a point to show any user-type related control in the app, you should read the current type and decide to whether show it or not.

Comment: I reworded your question based on what you said in your earlier comment. I also provided an answer that will solve your problem, Check it out!

Comment: How secure would this be?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is hide the button that pushes the view that only instructors can see, if the user is logged in is of type student.

In the view that has the button that pushes the view that only instructors can use do this:

In the .h file create a property for the button that pushes the view like so:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIButton *buttonThatPushesInstructorView;
```

In the .m file:

In the viewWillAppear method of the view do the following check:

```
  if ([[[PFUser currentUser]objectForKey:@"type"]isEqualToString:@"Instructor"]) {
        _buttonThatPushesInstructorView.hidden=NO;
    }else{

        _buttonThatPushesInstructorView.hidden=YES;
    }
```

This way, when the view loads, the button that pushes the instructor view will only be accessible to the users of type "Instructor".

Hope it helps!